# How do I structure my controller in Rails so that I can create multiple models on form submit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a Rails app (Rails 4.1.0) and I'm running into some trouble organizing the form logic. I think it is because I'm fundamentally missing some knowledge about Rails routing and how to handle it, so I apologize if this question is basic.

This is what my `routes.rb` looks like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users do
    resources :addresses
    resources :appointments
    resources :boxes do
      resources :statuses
    end
    resources :statuses
  end
end
```

The `User` signs up with their name, email, and password on the landing page. Afterwards, they are immediately presented with a form where they can create an `Appointment` and add an `Address` (using `fields_for` in my form - see below). This form is the same form that will be used for all future `Appointment` requests. Also, every time the `User` submits an `Appointment` request, a number of `Boxes` will be added to the database as well tied to the that `User`.

My question is, **where do I handle all of the logic for this form submit?** On the landing page, I have the form to create a new user. However, every time I add a new `Appointment`, would the I submit the form to the `create` method of the `Users` controller as well? That doesn't seem like the correct way to approach it since I'm creating an `Appointment` (and possibly creating/updating the `Address`).

I'm familiar with `fields_for` and I'm using it in my form. This is the form the user sees right after they sign up and are sent to their dashboard (which is right now, /users/show/:id). I have it rendered in a modal right now.

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

  <%= f.fields_for :appointments do |appt| %>
    <%= appt.date_select :appointment_date %>
    <%= appt.time_select :appointment_start_time %>
    <%= appt.time_select :appointment_end_time %>
    <%= appt.text_area :comments %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.fields_for :addresses do |addr| %>
    <%= addr.text_field :street_address %>
    <%= addr.text_field :street_address_optional %>
    <%= addr.text_field :city %>
    <%= addr.text_field :state %>
    <%= addr.number_field :zip_code %>
    <%= addr.check_box :primary %><%= builder.label :primary %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit "Sign Up" %>

<% end %>
```

This is what my UsersController looks like (haven't done anything with it yet except change the show method):

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
    @user = current_user
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        sign_in @user
        format.html { redirect_to new_appointment_url, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :new, status: :created, location: @appointment }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And here are my Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :boxes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :statuses, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :appointments, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses, :boxes, :statuses, :appointments
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class Box < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :statuses, dependent: :destroy
end

class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :box
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: If you need to handle anything manually, do it in the model layer. However, `accepts_nested_attributes_for` should do all the work for you. What exactly are the problems you're having?

Comment: In my `create` method of my `Users` controller, I have the logic to create a new User after the new user form is submitted. Should I place my logic for this new form also in the `create` method? Or should I have it somewhere else? Since all of my other models belong to `User`, there will be multiple places in my app where I submit data in a nested form. Should all of those nested forms also have their logic in the `create` method as well? Or would they go in other methods in the `User` controller? I'm having trouble exactly understanding where I would put this form logic. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us your `def user_params` in your controller? My suspicion is that it's missing an `:addresses_attributes` component.  It should probably look something like this (I'm just making up these attributes):

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, addresses_attributes: [:street, :city, :state]
end
```